# Different size form WPF - Design mode vs Runtime mode

Tags: wpf, forms, winforms, size

I'm sorry for the beginner's question but 'im quite newbie in creating WPF forms. 
I've some problems to set and viewing correct size of forms in Visual Studio.
In *design mode* the size is **larger** than in *runtime mode*.
Here the XAML. Any ideas???

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EnginedrawWPF"
    xmlns:h="http://helix-toolkit.org/wpf" x:Class="MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Motore di disegno" Height="400.0" Width="970.0" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">

    <h:HelixViewport3D x:Name="helixviewport3dobj"  Height="301" Margin="207,10,10.2,0" h:VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" Background="#FFC0E2B5" >

        <h:HelixViewport3D.DefaultCamera>
            <PerspectiveCamera Position="0,-3.5,3.5" LookDirection="0,3.5,-3.5" UpDirection="0,0,1" FieldOfView="61" NearPlaneDistance="0.001"/>
        </h:HelixViewport3D.DefaultCamera>
        <h:SunLight />
        <h:GridLinesVisual3D Fill="#FFB9B9B9" Thickness="0.01" MinorDistance="0.2" MajorDistance="1"/>
    </h:HelixViewport3D>
    <Button x:Name="CBlineare" Content="Nuovo tratto lineare" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181"/>
    <Button x:Name="CBcurva90" Content="Aggiungi curva 90°" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="10,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181"/>
    <Button x:Name="CBcurva45" Content="Aggiungi curva 45°" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="10,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181"/>
</Grid> 
</Window>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

You may put Grid tag inside the original Grid tag, with Height and Width set manually to fit into the design size.
Then you put the `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` to the Window tag.

Example of MainWindow.xaml (Visual Studio 2017 Community + WPF):

```
<Window x:Class="_171207_t0936_controlLocation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_171207_t0936_controlLocation"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="378.431" Width="607.353"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <!-- In order to avoid the difference in size of debug and run modes -->
        <!-- set "SizeToContent=WidthAndHeight" -->
        <!-- Then put Grid insdie the original Grid with Height and Width set manually -->
        <!-- to fit into the design size -->
        <Grid>
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Margin="430,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow Grid Layout as mentioned in the below link, which will resize controls based on window size

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514525(v=vs.90).aspx

Give height as d:DesignHeight="400*" and height=400* which will dynamically resize the layout.

Comment: it seems the problem is connected in some scale factor.. i don't get the solution. I also try to set d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="970" Width="970" Height="400" each in my XAML.

Comment: Instead of giving height as d:DesignHeight="400"  add * to end of each height and width like d:DesignHeight="400*" and height=400* which will dynamically resize the layout